# Confusion in Linux grep command

Tags: grep

I have a very basic confusion about grep. Suppose I have a following file to grep in:

```
test.txt:
This is an article 
from some newspaper
Article is good 
newspaper is not.
```

Now if I grep with following expression

```
grep -P "is\s*g" test.txt
```

I get the line:

```
Article is good
```

However if I do this:

```
grep -P "is*g" test.txt
```

I don't get anything. My question is since asterix (*) is a wildcard which represents 0 or more repetitions of the previous character, shouldn't the output of grep be the same. Why the zero or more repetitions of 's' is not giving any output?

What am I missing here. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because there's nothing in your input that matches `i`, then 0 or more repetitions of `s`, then `g`. "Article is good"  can't match because it has a space after the `s`, not a `g`. The pattern `is\s*g` matches because `\s` is a special pattern that matches any sort of whitespace — so the overall pattern is `is`, then any amount of space, then `g`, which naturally matches "is g".

Comment: Ohh...yes I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: s* means 0 or more repetitions of s not of space so ofcourse it won't match a space!!

Answer (score 3):

I see no `ig`, `isg`, `issg`, `issssg` in your input...

Since I don't know what you *wanted* to match, here is my best guess:

```
grep -P "is.*g" test.txt
```

Comment: yep, I got confused. Now I understand.

Answer (score 1):

You should see regular expression first before you use grep, also you will find it usefull with other commands... http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 0):

It's 0 or more repetition of the previous regex *atom*, and that atom is `\s`. So `\s*` can match tab-space-tab-space-space.